# Data Comparison Tool ignoring tables

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I don't know why, and I have run a bunch of tests, but for some reason, when I compare 2 versions of the same schema database, one filled with data and another empty, a particular table is ignored!
I've checked and it has a PK, a few rows, a clustered index, FKs, permissions and everything like all other tables... but for some reason, data compare doesn't even "list" it on the "choose what tables to compare data" form...

Anyone has any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: Could there be a permission issue?

Comment: @PeterSchneider checked it and updated question. tks!

Comment: Is there anything different about the table which isn't showing to the others (there was an issue mentioned around data compression here: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/773928/ssdt-schema-comparison-sqlpackage-and-data-compresssion)

Comment: @JohnLBevan actually no... nothing like that...